# Связь философии с филологией

Tags: литература, история

Как связаны филология и философия у Ницше?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Не очень поняла вопрос.Прямо связаны. Философия Ницше опирается на мифологию и филологию. Вот его вступительная речь, произнесенная в Базельском университете 28 мая 1869 г "Гомер и классическая филология":

http://nietzsche.ru/works/other/gomer/

И здесь почитайте:

http://magazines.russ.ru/nlo/2005/75/ia2.html

http://otherreferats.allbest.ru/philosophy/00094164_0.html